# EF6.1 optional-to-optional with fluent api mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following entity:

```
public class Revision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? PreviousRevisionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Revision PreviousRevision { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to create optional-to-optional relationship within the same entity using `PreviousRevision` as a navigation property and `PreviousRevisionId` as a foreign key Id for it.
I know that it can be done by annotating `PreviousRevisionId` property with `[ForeignKey("PreviousRevision")]` attribute, but what about fluent api?

I tried:

```
HasOptional(c => c.PreviousRevision)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("PreviousRevisionId"));
```

, but doing migration I'm getting error:

> PreviousRevisionId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique.
>   Property name 'PreviousRevisionId' is already defined.

So, basically, it looks impossible with fluent API. But I thought that annotation functionalty is a subset of fluent API functionality, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MapKey` is used when you don't want to have the foreign key as a property in your model class and you want to rename the FK column name that EF gives by default in your DB.

So, you have two options here:

- You can map your one to one relationship as you are trying before but
  you need to delete `PreviousRevisionId` property:

  ```
  HasOptional(c => c.PreviousRevision).WithOptionalDependent();// If you want now you can rename the FK column using .Map(m => m.MapKey("PreviousRevisionId"));
  ```
- Or you can create an unidirectional one to many relationship:

  ```
  HasOptional(c => c.PreviousRevision).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.PreviousRevisionId);
  ```

I think the last option is more suited to what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, second solution suits me, yet it looks strange that I need to define relationship as one-to-many when i know that it is actually one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
public class Revision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? PreviousRevisionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Revision PreviousRevision { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Revision > PreviousRevisions { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
HasMany(a => a.PreviousRevisions).WithOptional(p => p.PreviousRevision ).HasForeignKey(p => p.PreviousRevisionId )
```